# Как перехватить ответ команды в bash

Tags: bash, linux

Использую команду "find". хочу создать условие при успешном нахождении файла и при не успешном. интересует не столько строчка кода (хотя и это тоже), сколько сам способ перехвата возможных ответов команд.

Comment: find ведет себя как любая обычна linux команда. Она возвращает 0, если все хорошо.

Comment: Правда, все хорошо (код возврата == 0), это не означает, что хоть что-то найдено.

--

Для поиска по имени файла можно добавить в конвейер `grep` на это же имя.

    avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ find . -name xaxa123
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ echo $?
    0
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ find . -name xaxa123 | grep xaxa123
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ echo $?
    1
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ find . -name xaxa | grep xaxa
    ./tst/prog/xaxa
    ./tst/xaxa
    ./lib/xaxa
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ echo $?
    0
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ 

А вообще, не очень понятно, что именно хочет ТС.

Comment: @avp тогда уж так:

    find /dir/ -name '*.php' -printf "found\n" |grep -q -m1 found
         |_директория  |_маска    |_печатать found  |_молча найти только первое совпадение
    echo $? #если 0 - нашли

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[[@shaman888](/users/11102/shaman888)](/users/11102/shaman888), судя по написанному Вами коду, для начала надо бы прочитать `man bash`, `man find` и `man grep`.

--

Логика тут действительно простая. Если Вас интересует не столько строчка кода (хотя и это тоже), сколько сам способ перехвата возможных ответов команд, то вкратце:

find ищет в заданном *дереве каталогов* файлы, например, с заданным именем и для каждого файла выполняет заданные действия (по умолчанию печатает его имя).

```
 find ./ -name doc.txt -printf "found\n"
```

Вот эта команда для каждого найденного в дереве текущих каталогов файла с именем `doc.txt` будет печатать строку `found`. Кстати, если будет найден каталог (сокет, fifo и др.) с тем же именем, то тоже напечатает. Если требуется ограничиться только файлами (а также это полезно, если не хотим зависнуть на каком-нибудь fifo-файле, в случае действий, задаваемых -exec), то добавим условие, что нас интересуют только обычные файлы

```
find ./ -type f -name doc.txt -printf "found\n"
```

перед проверкой на имя.

Однако, нам нужен не вывод на экран, а некий признак, найдено ли что-нибудь. Вывод же на экран подавить легко, достаточно перенаправить stdout команды в `/dev/null`.

Мы знаем, что команды обычно устанавливают *код возврата* для того, чтобы сказать о результате своего выполнения, но команда `find` возвращает 0 (т.е. ОК) независимо от того, нашла она что-то или нет.

Поэтому такая конструкция

```
if find ./ -type f -name doc.txt -printf "found\n" >/dev/null ; then
  echo Found
else
  echo Not found
fi
```

**не сработает** (всегда будет found). Кстати, код возврата последней из выполненных команд находится в переменной `$?` (нормальное завершение команды - это `$?` равно 0). Можно анализировать его так

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo Found
fi
```

или так

```
if [ $? ]; then
  echo Found
fi
```

а можно сразу проверить в  `if command ...`, как выше.

Обратите внимание, что когда мы анализируем команду, то `[ ... ]` **не ставятся**. (На самом деле shell воспринимает  открывающую `[`, как команду `test` (*я не говорю, что реально ее вызывает*), которая вычисляет свои аргументы и возвращает код (0 - ОК -> then ветка), а закрывающая `]` нужна просто для проверки забывчивости программиста.

В принципе можно написать такую конструкцию (уже работает(!))

```
list=`find . -type f -name $1`
if [ "$list" != "" ]; then
  echo Found
else
  echo Not found
fi
```

которая перенаправит stdout команды в переменную. Обратите  внимание на то, что имя переменной в левой части операции присваивания **без символа $**, а вот внутри `if` с ним. Символ `$` перед переменной означает, что мы должны "раскрыть" ее, т.е. подставить в текст вместо имени переменной ее значение.

Далее в `if` проверяется, что полученный текст (строка) не пустой. Для сравнения строк на равенство в `if` используются операции `==` и `!=`, а чисел `-eq` и `-ne`.

Но такое решение весьма затратно. Поэтому по совету [[@eicto](/users/11304/eicto)](/users/11304/eicto) напишем так:

```
if find . -name doc.txt -printf found  | grep -q -m1 found ; then
  echo Found
else 
  echo Not found
fi
```

Здесь применим команду `grep` для анализа stdout команды `find`, которая будет писать строку `found`, когда обнаруживает файл `doc.txt`. Вот **grep возвращает нужный нам код**, если искомый аргумент (в нашем случае *`found`* в stdin grep-а) найден.

Причем ключ `-q` говорит grep, что ничего на stdout выводить не надо, а ключ `-m1`, что после первого найденного слова *`found`* надо завершиться.

На всякий случай код

```
#!/bin/bash

# Поиск файла, заданного аргументом 1 в текущем каталоге
# Можно искать несколько "похожих файлов", если задать маску (звездлчки и т.п.)

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then # проверим количество аргументов
    echo Usage $0 filename
    exit 2
fi

# отключим расширение метасимволов в имени файла, 
# иначе получим не одно имя. а список и find не будет правильно работать
set -f

if find . -name $1 -printf found  | grep -q -m1 found ; then
    echo Found.
else 
    echo Not found.
    exit 1
fi

# по умолчанию код возврата все равно будет 0, но для порядку...
exit 0
```

для поиска в текущем оглавлении файла, задаваемого первым аргументом.

Comment: Я бы написал

    find . -name $1 -printf found **-quit**

чтобы не гонять поиск, если файл уже найден.

Comment: @VladD, тоже верно (и как Вы помните все флаги :)?). 

Хотя -m1 в grep для того же, конвейер-то оборвется, но с -quit красивей.

Comment: @avp: Я помнил только, что то-то такое есть, точное название подсмотрел в `man find`. Насчёт конвейера, пример без `-quit`, но с `-m1` на моём cygwin'е продолжал бежать до момента, когда `find` нашёл _второй_ файл и попытался записать `found` в pipe во второй раз (нету нормального юникса под рукой, так что не уверен, что это правильное поведение). Да, и там ещё надо бы поменять `-printf found` на `-printf 'found\n'`.

Comment: @VladD, @avp grep-grep'ом, но `wc -l` -- полегче будет. И `found` выводить не обязательно

Comment: @alexlz, @avp: [интернет](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/find-command-return-true-if-a-file-was-found-881400/) предлагает такой вариант, вообще без конвейера:

    case `find . -name $1 -print -quit` in
      '') echo 'Not found' ;;
      *) echo 'Found' ;;
    esac

Comment: Да, учитывая, что у find есть флаг -quit, это правильно. 

Тогда также подойдет

    first=`find . -type f -name $1 -quit`
    if [ "$first" != "" ]; then
      echo Found $first
    else
      echo Not found
    fi

Вот сколько способов перехвата возможных ответов команд мы нарисовали!

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

list=`find ./*.php`
echo $list;
```

Comment: вот что я написал:

#!/bin/bash
$list=`find doc.txt |grep -q -m1 found`
# найти файл doc.txt, после чего прекратить поиск молча 
if [-a "$list"]
# если файл существует то
then 
 echo "There is doc.txt";
else
# если не существует то
 echo "doc.txt lost";
fi

echo "End";
# сообщение о завершении скрипта



Только скрипт не работает. Логика тут вроде достаточно простая. Как сделать его работоспособным?

Comment: @shaman888 что-то Вы очень странное написали. Да и @dimka3210 серьёзно наврал. Вы где задаёте имя искомого файла? или это всегда doc.txt(1)? Строка `$list=find doc.txt |grep -q -m1 found` -- полный бред. RTFM (2). Попробуйте так

    #!/bin/bash
    if [[ `find . -name doc.txt | wc -l` != 0 ]]
    then
      echo good
    else
      echo bad
    fi

или строку с if записать

    if (( `find . -name doc.txt | wc -l` ))